# setting baud rate for UsbDeviceConnection

Tags: android, usb, baud-rate

I am trying to get Android USB host mode to work; but I need to set the baud rate to 56000. I only found this code:

```
UsbDeviceConnection myConnection;
myConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, null, 0, 0);//baudrate 9600
```

In the references I did not find anything about this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command shown contains the baud rate divisor. A good explanation for the calculation of baud rates is (here)[ http://www.mev.co.uk/pages/Support/USB-Baud-Spoof.html ]